# Can werewolves detect relics created by strong emotion?

Tags: magic-items, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

I'm just getting back up to speed on Werewolf, and I'm looking at dropping some relics (Reliquary/Armory Reloaded) in front of a werewolf character. I suspect these things resonate in the spirit world. Would the werewolf be able to better sense these items without doing anything? What ways could they use to determine that the items are not normal? References would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A relic is most likely (though not necessarily) a fetish or a locus, I think.**

**If it is a fetish**, detecting them is simple:

> Fetishes are what would otherwise be mundane items or elements
>   fashioned together and made into vessels or traps for spirits. (...)
>   Recognizing a fetish or talen for what it is requires an Intelligence
>   + Occult roll.

*– p.204, Fetishes, WtF core*

**If the relic is a locus** – because, remember, loci can not only be "fixed position" objects, despite what most of the RAW seems to indicate:

> A locus isn’t an independent entity like a spirit is. It’s just a
>   patch of ground, **a creature, a person or an object** that has an
>   affinity for a particular kind of spiritual energy.

*– p.47, Loci, WtF core* (emphasis mine),

and for an example:

> One of these artifacts, they discover, has awakened as a small locus,
>   and as people come too close to it, they are being drawn right through
>   the Gauntlet to the spirit world.

*– p.235, sample story, WtF core*

...so, if the relic is a locus like the artifacts mentioned above, detecting them isn't too hard either:

> Werewolves can automatically sense when they’re in a locus’ area of
>   effect. They can tell by the prickling of their hackles that the
>   spirit world is nearer where they stand. If a werewolf wishes to
>   determine the precise location of a locus, his player makes a Wits +
>   Investigation + Primal Urge roll as a standard action to determine the
>   general direction of the locus itself. Success gives him the general
>   direction to the locus. An exceptional success, if he’s within line of
>   sight, will allow him to recognize the locus’s material form.

*– p.261-262, Loci (Spirit Locus Influence), WtF core*

However, pinpointing them, and finding their exact location isn't too easy either. Witness:

> loci themselves cannot be detected with physical senses alone. An
>   observant werewolf can spot their influence — the slow resonant
>   distortion of the Shadow and the inevitable groups of spirits
>   harvesting its Essence — but finding the locus itself often requires a
>   measure of investigative work.

*– p. 263 "Changes in the Flesh", WtF core*